# Creating Tile Cache using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, tilecache, geocortex

I have a large dataset which I need to display in an online map. We use Geocortex and ArcGIS Online services. I have heard of tile cache, but I can't work out what I need to do to create it.

Can I do it in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how things are loaded in GeoCortex, but there are two options to create a Tiled Map for use online.

The first option is to create a Tiled Service for use in ArcGIS Online (AGOL). To do this follow these steps:

1) Open an mxd with the image you want to tile. Ensure you fill in all the 
 "map document properties" information - Title, Tags etc. Also make sure that the map you want to share has the Coordinate System you wish to use set.

2) Select "File" in the top left corner of the MXD, then select "Share As", then "Service..."

3) In the dialogs that follow, you want to "Publish a Service",  set your AGOL account as the connection, and a name for the service, click next and choose a folder in AGOL where you want to store the service...you can pretty much use the defaults here.

4) The next window that pops up is the "Service Editor". This is where you create your cache. You will see at the bottom of the editor, there is a "Caching" option, click this. It will open the menu's for creating your tiled image cache. The first option you need to select the Draw this map service: "Using tiles from a cache" radio button. You can leave the Tiling Scheme as "ArcGIS Online / Bing Maps / Google Maps".

5) The next series of instructions detail how to control the level of detail the tiled cache will show when published online. Using the sliders you can control the Scale Levels. The left-most button is the minimum scale level, the right-most is the Maximum Scale level. Under the slider you will see a description of what or where the scale level is most appropriate. This description is usefel because you can get a sense of what is best. I.e: Country Scale to Building / Houses Scale.

6) You can "Calculate" the Cache size to get an idea of the how much space your cache will take up online. If you wish, you can select the "Advanced Settings" and choose the Area of interest to cach to be "Current extent of the map", this can greatly reduce the cache size.

Hit publish when you done, the process will analyse your map and provide feedback if there are any errors. It will then publish. You can view the service in AGOL and consume it.

**Just a note, these cached tiles can get quite large, and when publishing to AGOL it can use service credits. So just be aware.**

If you want to avoid using AGOL, and create a Tiled Package to moce around and try and side load onto a device (Like Collector for ArcGIS). Then follow these steps.

Follow Step 1 from above, then select "File" and "Share As" as before, but select "Tile Package".

This brings up a simple "Tile Package" dialog, where you can control the details for your Tile Package. The tab menu "Tile Package" lets you choose a local save for the package - so where you want it to be saved.

"Tile Format" lets you control how the package will be tiled. You can select the level of detail (Scale) and subsequest size of the package.

"Item Description" will let you fill in any details for the package you might want to keep with the package file.

Share the package and you will get a single file containing a tiled image that you can (at last in Collector - and I am sure in GeoCortex too) as a backdrop / background to the online data.

Comment: Thank you. GeoCortex uses services from AGOL. As long it is a service with a link, it should work.  Because of the size of the tiles, in the first option, is there a way to keep actual files (tiles) on my pc or a server rather than on ArcGIS online?

Comment: Best bet (from my limited understanding), is to publish to a Server (Server for ArcGIS) and then load the service from AGOL from the Server. The only other option for keeping the files on a local machine is to use the second option.

Comment: If you create a .tpk tile package (@Keagan describes the process of creating a tile package in the second half of his answer) you can keep on your pc and even drag and drop into ArcMap (not Pro) You can also upload the .tpk to the server and use it as a hosted tile layer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a ArcGIS Server instance where you can publish the MapService too. From here you are able to use the Caching Tools to define the cache properties and then trigger the build process of the cache.

http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/creating-a-map-cache.htm